# Add UIViewController in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

i want to display a UIViewController in a cocos2d project, so i have do this in my CCLayer class:

```
-(void)displayMainMenu {
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Marker Felt"];
    [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:26];

    CCMenuItemFont *openViewC = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Open View" target:self selector:@selector(loadMyViewController)];
    mainMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:openViewC, nil];
    [self addChild:mainMenu z:0];
}

-(void) loadMyViewController{

    //Add the tableview when the transition is done
    myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    UIView *viewHost = hostView.view;

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:viewHost];
}
```

and then in my ViewController to return to my CCLayer i do this:

```
- (IBAction)exitAction:(id)sender
    {
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [MainMenu scene]]; //i need it or not?
}
```

and all work, i use cocos2d v2.0, but i want know if there is a better way to add a UIViewController in a cocos2d scene, thanks!

Comment: To avoid a leak add MyViewController als childViewController to the Director and release myView after its added. On remove, remove myView and its view from the superview. myView covers the eaglview where the CCNodes are rendered. So you dont need to push and pop CCLayers.

Comment: can you explain it better in an answer? thanks, i'm waiting for it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the director in cocos2d 2.0 is a subclass of UIViewController as the root of a navigation controller loaded in the AppDelegate, there is actually a very simple way that can utilize UIKit animations, if you prefer that. It also leaves the scene intact without really worrying about memory management. You could alter your -loadMyViewController method to this:

```
- (void)loadMyViewController {
     myView = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
     AppController *app = (AppController *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     [app.navController pushViewController:myView animated:YES];
     [CCDirector sharedDirector].pause;
}
```

And then simply resume the director and call [app.navController popViewController...] when you want to return to the cocos2d scene. Alternatively, you could use the stopAnimation method when you push your view controller instead of pause, similar to how cocos2d handles the app entering the background.

Comment: Can you still get callbacks, etc from uikit controls inside cocos2d nodes?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple code if you want to pop up a view , just import yourviewcontroller.h file and use this code that supports all cocos2d versions

```
- (void)loadMyViewController {

     yourviewcontroller  *myView = [[yourviewcontroller alloc] init];

     UIView *viewHost = myView.view;

    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:viewHost];
```

}

//Replace the screen if you want to reduce memory usage or just pause it

Answer (score 1):

If it is cocos2D 2.0, then use this.

```
AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [app.navController.view addSubview:newView];
```

Bellow cocos2d 2.0

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app .viewController.view addSubview:newView];
```

Comment: It's better than my solution?

Answer (score 1):

OR you can use this code..

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];

AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[[app navController] presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```